# wordpress pass data to rest service via contact form

Tags: wordpress, rest, webforms, contacts, contact-form-7

Is there a way to do it please? Any plugins maybe or code modifications?

I am currently using Contact Form 7 plugin and would like to redirect the form output to a remote rest service rather than to an email address.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, here's a [post that describes how to do it with MailChimp](http://www.bigbossmas.com/wordpress/integrating-contact-form-7-to-mailchimp-the-better-way/)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. So in order to redirect the form output to my rest service do I just need the same mailchimp credentials?

Comment: Most REST services require an API key to authenticate, including MailChimp.